# Using Vue.js / Bootstrap-vue.js CDN and components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cdn

forgive my ignorance here, I am super new to Vue. I am looking for a way to utilize bootstrap-Vue from CDN (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/ click browser on right nav). I am not seeing how to call the components. Using the webpack / CLI version, no problems, but CDN, I am lost at how to use this.

I put up a simple codepen.io to test this. I've added the CSS and js files per the docs.

https://codepen.io/jasonflaherty/pen/rrzbxj

```
//do I need this?
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

//try individual components.
import { Card } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';
Vue.use(Card);
```

What am I missing to utilize bootstrap-vue.js CDN? Do I need to import differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just include the required CDN below and without invoking `Vue.use(XXX)`
(There is a [Basic example](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/starter-templates/) from the official website.)

```html
        <!-- Required Stylesheets -->
        <link
          type="text/css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        />
        <link
          type="text/css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"
        />

        <!-- Required scripts -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
```

When you run the [Basic example](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/starter-templates/), you will get the bootstrap decoration.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you use the CDN, you do not need to `use` the BootstrapVue plugin; it will do that for you. Just including the script adds all the BootstrapVue components globally.

You cannot use ES6 `import` statements in the browser.

You *do* need to create a Vue.

Here is your [pen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/YjxbPm?editors=1010).

Answer (score 1):

You should to use a basic structure of Vue. So, your JS should be:

```
const vue = new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

And is necessary that your HTML code stay into a:

```
<div id="app">
   <!-- ...your code -->
</div>
```

Comment: Right, I should have wrapped my html in <div id="app">...</div>